# Installing Scrapy package within Python Environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, pycharm

This is my very first attempt with both Python and Scrapy

I have installed Scrapy in a virtual environment called `scrapy-env` using the following commands:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv `scrapy-env`
cd `scrapy-env`
pip install scrapy
```

Now I am trying to write my first Python file, which is a spider, I have created a file called spider1.py under the following path:

*~/scrapy-env/spider_practice/spider_practice/spiders/spider1.py*

I am using pycharm editor, which is complaining about not having Scrapy package installed:

[image]

If I click on Install Package Scrapy then I get the following message:

[image]

I am not sure why scrapy is not imported at the first place, I thought I have created an environment and installed scrapy? How should I resove this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to install scrapy inside a virtual
environment.

In python you can create virtual environment venv which is very handy:

Usage of virtualenv is deprecated.

**To create virtual environment:**

```
python3 -m venv scrapy_env
```

**To activate virtual environment:**

```
source scapy_env/bin/activate
```

**To install scrapy:**

```
pip install scrapy
```

Open IDE and set scrapy_env/bin/python3 or required python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Use *pipenv* for creating virtual environment

*may be you are running on lower then 3.5 version* **Scrapy runs on Python 3.5 or above**

install pipenv with pip3

> pip3 install pipenv

install scrapy with pip3

> pip3 install Scrapy

create virtual environment with python "whichever_python_version_you_have"

> pipenv install --python 'python_version'

to create virtual  environment

> pipenv run

now check in your folder's **pip** file. in this file you can see which python version you are using